# Como colocar o menu boostrap no meio da tela?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Observem a imagem;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[Clique aqui](https://jsfiddle.net/2ar2x3tq/)

Como faço para esse menu ficar no meio da tela?
A dificuldade existe porque estou usando Bootstrap 4, já tentei de tudo.

Queria que ficasse semelhante a esse abaixo;

www.esperancapaixao.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Na documentação oficial é usada a classe `justify-content-md-center` para fazer isso. Assim fica centralizado só até telas MD. Link dos exemplos oficiais https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/navbars/

***OBS:*** Como é responsivo tem que executar como "Página toda"

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Veja como fica no exemplo abaixo:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExample08" aria-controls="navbarsExample08"
            aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-md-center" id="navbarsExample08">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Centered nav only
                        <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="dropdown08" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true"
                        aria-expanded="false">Dropdown</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown08">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Onde tem a listagem dos menus, se você for ver o código fonte vê que o `ul` tem `margin-right:auto !important`, ou seja, ele irá encostar ao lado esquerdo. Então basta adicionar-lhe um `style` com o seguinte código.

```
<ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto" style="margin: auto!important">
```

E para pôr o `HOME` junto aos restantes menus, terá de mudá-lo para dentro do `ul` mas fará com que ele desapareça na vista para `mobile` e apareça junto dos menus

Comment: FICOU MUITO BOM, muito obrigado.

Comment: @wladyband O facto de o Home ficar fora de vista em mobile não fez mal?